# Spark List: ensureIndexIsVisible with expanding list itemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Spark List with an expanding itemRenderer (snippet of it below). It works very well but I am struggling to display the fully expanded list item when calling `ensureIndexIsVisible`. I've tried various things with validate/invalidate to try to force the `List` to take the expanded item size into account but either I am doing it wrong or the `List` component isn't built to handle this.

In the image below, I've called `myList.ensureIndexIsVisible(7);`Item 7 is expanded and the header scrolled to be visible but most of the expanded item is offscreen.

Anyone know a way to address this?

**Update:** If the `List` is specified to have [useVirtualLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS64909091-7042-4fb8-A243-8FD4E2990264.html#WS486D1976-E12C-4654-B330-3DF3B23614F6)="false" then the following works:

```
   myList.validateNow();
   myList.ensureIndexIsVisible(expandIndex);
```

but of course if there are a lot of cells in the List instance then this is a problem.

---

[image]

```
        protected function expandOne_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var expandIndex:Number = Number(expandTarget.text);
            data.getItemAt(expandIndex).selected = true;
            myList.invalidateDisplayList();
            myList.ensureIndexIsVisible(expandIndex);
            myList.validateNow();
        }
```

---

**List itemRenderer:**

```
    <s:CheckBox id="eventName" 
            label="{data.eventName}" 
            top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" 
            skinClass="skins.SatelliteEventSkin" 
            selected="{data.selected}"
            click="{data.selected = !data.selected}"/>

    <s:VGroup includeInLayout="{eventName.selected}" 
          visible="{eventName.selected}" 
          top="30" left="10" right="10" bottom="10">

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" width="100%" >
        <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
        <s:Label  text="eventID"/>
        <s:Label id="eventID" 
                 width="150"
                 text="{data.eventID}"/>
    </s:HGroup> 

    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **selectedIndex** value or just scroll your List using **verticalScrollPosition** value -`myList.layout.verticalScrollPosition += your_item_height;`.

Comment: thanks. That works only if `useVirtualLayout = true` (but then `validateNow();` with `ensureIndexIsVisible();`works in that case too). Was trying to avoid having `useVirtualLayout = false` and rendering all the cells.